# A Question on a property of Lebesgue integrals

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $f$ be a measurable function on $E$ which can be expressed as $f=g+h$, where $g$ is finite and integrable over $E$, and $h$ is a measurable, non-negative function on $E$. Define $$\int_{E} f dm =\int_{E} g dm + \int_{E} h dm$$.

Show that this is properly defined in the sense that it is independent of a particular choice of finite integrable function and a non-negative measurable function whose sum is $f$.

My attempt. So Let us take $f=g_{1}+h_{1}$, where $g_{1}$ is finite integrable over $E$, $h_{1}$ is non-negative and measurable. From there what I want to prove is $$\int_{E} g dm + \int_{E} h dm = \int_{E} g_{1} dm + \int_{E} h_{1} dm $$

After this I cannot proceed . I think I have to use linearity of lebesgue integrals but the linearity has its own restriction. I cannot apply linearity arbitrarily! How can this be solved?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Prove that if $\int h=\infty$ then $\int h_1=\infty$ too. The case when they are not is easy.

Comment: So, $g+h=g_{1}+h_{1} \implies h=-g +g_{1} +h_{1}$. Now suppose that $\int h = \infty$ and $\int h_{1} < \infty $, then using the from $\int h = \int (g_{1}-g +h_{1})$, using linearity we get $\int h < \infty$... contradiction. Is it right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.